# Multiply number with decimal C# beginner

Tags: c#, decimal

So i'm very new at C# and programming in general and I have come across a problem i'm not able to find via google.

I got a user input that can be either a integer or a decimal which is stored in the variabel price.

But I'm not able to multiply (the value of)price with 0,12 or 0,25 decimal numbers that is to say. Here is my code.

```
            VAT = price *Decimal.(0,12);
```

VS says it wants and identifier, so I guess the problem is that I have to tell VS that it is decimals but I don't know how.

Sorry if this is really a stupid question but I just have to know.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing there. Have you tried VAT=price * 0.12;

Comment: @FeliceM it would make it `double`, not `decimal`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I have the feeling that the OP wants a number with a fractional part, not the C# `decimal` data type.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis that's possible, but for financial calculations (and I think VAT and price indicate that) `decimal` is better choice.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I hadn't noticed the variable names. You're absolutely right.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, yes I know. The OP asked to be able to multiply the two values. If he has difficulties for such simple task I do not thing he is ready to understand the differences between decimal and double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `m` to make numeric constant treated as `decimal`:

```
VAT = price * 0.12m;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making sure the VAT is also decimal, otherwise you will lose the decimal part of the result (if VAT is integer).

furthermore you do not need to convert 0.12 to decimal, you can use it as is, or put 'm' behind it to indicate that it is infact decimal.

it would then look like this:

VAT = price * 0.12m